# How to load images dynamically with image name using custom adapter

Tags: java, android

I am adding Images dynamically from URL. i am displaying Images but below that images i need to display respective name of the image dynamically and i am using custom adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imageName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Programmatically:

```
private View addImageViewWithText(Bitmap bitmap, String text) {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);// 'this' is a Context instance
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.weight = 1;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    layout.addView(imageView);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setText(text);

    layout.addView(textView);

    return layout;
}
```

On the adapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ...Code to get the view holder...

    holder.imgscrollchild.removeAllViews();
    for(int i=0; i<numOfImageViews;i++) {

        holder.imgscrollchild.addView(createimg(tempValues.getImage(), tempValues.getText()));
    }

    return horizontalLayout;
}
```

Note: I strongly recommend you use a [ViewHolder](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html).

Comment: horizontalLayout.addView(createimg(tempValues.getImage(),
     tempValues.getText()));

Comment: It is not displaying images now

Comment: LinearLayout horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
   horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
   // holder.imgscrollchild.removeAllViews();
   for (int i = 0; i < numOfImageViews; i++) {

    holder.imgscrollchild.addView(createimg(tempValues.getImage(),
      tempValues.getText()));
   }

   return horizontalLayout; this is correct...?

Comment: LinearLayout horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
   horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
   holder.imgscrollchild.removeAllViews();
   for (int i = 0; i < numOfImageViews; i++) {

    holder.imgscrollchild.addView(createimg(tempValues.getImage(),
      tempValues.getText()));
   }

   return horizontalLayout;

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69310/discussion-on-answer-by-torque203-how-to-load-images-dynamically-with-image-name).

Answer (score 0):

Use listview for your imagelist: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html